# How stop-start-restart-status stunnel as a service on centos 7.6

Tags: centos-7, stunnel

I've installed stunnel 4.5 on centos 7.6.

```
sudo yum -y install stunnel
```

Now i want to stop-start-restart-status stunnel as a service on centos 7.6.
The command below does not work :

```
systemctl start stunnel
```

How can i do that?

---

Take a look at this [link = starting_stopping_restarting_stunnel](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sect-starting_stopping_restarting_stunnel) :
The command

```
stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
```

Works.
But the command

```
kill `cat /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid`
```

Does not work.It tells :

> cat: /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid: No such file or directory

---

Here is `stunnel.conf` file that i've created in this path (`/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf`).

```
client = no
[squid]
accept  = 1800
connect = 127.0.0.1:8080
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

It works fine.

Comment: I found solution here : https://serverfault.com/questions/833702/centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel and here : https://github.com/liuliang/centos-stunnel-systemd/blob/master/README.md > Please write an answer based on two these links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution here :
[centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/833702/centos-with-selinux-systemd-and-stunnel)
and here :
[centos-stunnel-systemd](https://github.com/liuliang/centos-stunnel-systemd/blob/master/README.md)

---

And here is `stunnel.service` changes for centos 7.6 :

```
[Unit]
Description=SSL tunnel for network daemons
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=stunnel.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill stunnel

# Give up if ping don't get an answer
TimeoutSec=600

Restart=always
PrivateTmp=false
```

Now you can start-enable-stop stunnel as a service :

```
sudo systemctl start stunnel.service
sudo systemctl enable stunnel.service
sudo systemctl stop stunnel.service
```